# Get info on popup

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```
<button id="LearnMoreBtn" class="infobutton">Learn More</button>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="popup">
       somethin...
    <button id="CloseBtn">Close</button>
    </div>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("LearnMoreBtn").onclick = function(){
    var x = $('.carousel .item.active');
    var infoText = x.attr('info-text');
    //alert(infoText);
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    popup.style.display = "block";
};

document.getElementById("CloseBtn").onclick = function(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    popup.style.display = "none";      
}
};
</script>
```

and i would like to display "infoText" instead of "somethin..." and i really can't find out how. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `popup.innerHTML = infoText`

Take a look over here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/75B3eyFdkOj4S0ZkoLZ7?p=preview

If you use the innerHTML, the button would also disappear so i put it outside.

Another possible solution would be if you create another div inside your `popup`that holds the content.

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="content">blablabla</div>
    <button id="CloseBtn">Close</button>
</div>
```

and in your script you then use `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = infoText;`

Comment: Thanks! It works but now i can't close the popup. I think that is because of css because on your it works

Comment: @RobertoDiglio glad I could help you. Can you mark it as solved? What is your problem with css?

Comment: I don't know. When i click the popup shows the info but then i can't close it. The fact is that on your plnkr it works, on my page it doesn't. If i delete "popup.innerHTML = whatever" it begin to works again.